# Cleanly reinstalling an application

Tags: software-installation, settings

I am currently having problems with Hulu desktop, and want to reinstall it.  However, when I attempt to uninstall and reinstall it, it saves my previous settings (even my username and password).

How can I get it to completely uninstall and reinstall, so that it doesn't remember any previous settings?  A general solution would be nice, in case I ever run into a similar problem.

Comment: Can you provide some details about how you installed it, your distro, package manager, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your user configuration data. From what I've just tested, this resides in following files in your user's home directory:

```
 .huludesktop
 .config/.huludesktop.data
 .local/share/.huludesktop.data
```

Removing those should fix the problem. If not, try searching for more using `find ~/ -name "*hulu*"`.